# Problem while trying to connect from R to SQL server using a service account not the default Windows authentication

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I am in a corporate environment. Using packages `DBI` and `odbc` I can easily establish a connection between R and a SQL database like that:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  driver = SQL.driver,
  server = SQL.server,
  database = SQL.database,
  encoding = SQL.encoding
)
```

I understood that, without specific UID/PWD, the Windows authentication is used by `DBI`.

Since this R code will have to run on an external server (in fact, it is a shiny application behind), I need to specify a UID/PWD, and for that I requested and get "service account" from my IT department.

However, as soon as I specify the service account UID/PWD to `DBI::dbConnect()` I get a login failure:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc()
  ,driver = SQL.driver
  ,server = SQL.server
  ,database = SQL.database
  ,encoding = SQL.encoding
  ,UID = SQL.UID
  ,PWD = SQL.PWD
)
# Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 28000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxxxxxxx'.
```

If I manually open MS SQL server and try to connect with this service account using the "SQL server authentication method" instead of "Windows authentication" I also have the same error.

According to the IT department, this is "normal" and I think I am supposed to launch MS SQL server using this service account as user, then to use the Windows authentication to connect. Funny thing is that we are not allowed to "run as" another user.

Therefore, assuming this mechanic would work, **how one can mimic this behavior in R** please?

Comment: Do you have any access to the server? There might [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15) in the error log on exactly why the login failed. One of the possibilities that I've seen often is that the server doesn't have SQL authentication enabled--[here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15) how to enable it.

Comment: I can connect to the server using my windows credentials as stated above, I can read/write on SQL tables, but can't apply any modification to the server itself (no rights).

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure if you meant the same server in both parts. If this is a server running elsewhere (not on your local computer) then there's a miscommunication between you and your IT dept. It does make perfect sense to use a service account to run the SQL Server instance, but it would be a Windows user or MSA rather than a SQL-authentication user. If they did create a SQL-authenticated login, then their advice doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar set up at work with personal creds and service acct creds to a MS SQLServer db. I use the following to connect with the service account...

Note that you will have to download the [mssql jdbc jar file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
username <= "myusername"
password <- "mypassword"
drv <- RJDBC::JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                   'mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar')
connection_string <- paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.10.01\\srv1;databaseName=dbname;user=", 
                            username, ";password=", password, ";")
conn <- RJDBC::dbConnect(drv, connection_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, due to our setup we can't use java based solution (common error "JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry"). Anyhow for others who can, to what correspond "//10.10.10.01\\srv1"? Should it be replaced with the SQL server address?

Comment: The JAVA_HOME error can probably be overcome, but it sounds like that's not the direction you want to go. As for the other question, it's the URL / IP address for the database.

Comment: Unfortunately some colleagues and I tried several times to fix this JAVA HOME error without success, we at the end face a access/right/whatever issue. Thanks for your proposal but I can't test it hence approve it for now.